# In the broker2.liq example, how is storage being returned by the call function?

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

The code [here](https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/blob/next/tests/others/broker2.liq) returns value from Contract.call() as:

```
let _result, storage = Contract.call storage.x transfer storage () in
```

What are the values stored in _result and storage?

Note: I couldn't compile this in the online liquidity editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an obsolete example. Contract calls do not return values anymore (it should not be in the repo). Have a look [here](https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/blob/next/tests/others/auction.liq) instead (contract calls create operations that are executed sequentially after the calling contract execution terminates, note that the operations must be returned in order at the end).

Comment: Can you give some detail on "must be returned in order at the end"?